# Mamp Pro Nginx 502 Bad Gateway in WordPress admin-ajax.php

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, mamp, mamp-pro

I've recently migrated a WordPress site:

From: Mamp Pro / Apache / PHP 5.6.32 / MySQL 5.5.38

To: Mamp Pro / Nginx / PHP 7.0.14 / MySQL 6.5.38

One issue I've been having is in the WP 'Add New Post' screen, I'm getting a 502 (Bad Gateway) error in the console log coming from wp-admin/admin.ajax.php.

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

add to nginx conf

```
fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
```